# Is there a way to set an onClick to change background of a div element to a gradient using JavaScript/React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background, gradient

This is my code for my functions (I'm using react by the way):

```
 function egg() {
    setBG("Black");
  }
  function egg1() {
    setBG("rgba(0, 77, 194, 1)");
  }
  function egg2() {
    setBG("rgba(10, 97, 17, 1)");
  }
  function egg3() {
    setBG("#00ff87");
  }
  function egg4() {
    setBG("#d61e1e");
  }
  function egg5() {
    setBG("#d62976");
  }
  function egg6() {
    setBG("Black");
  }
  function egg7() {
    setBG("#f96854");
  }
```

Is there a way to have the setBG() to contain a gradient? I have tried replacing it with linear-gradient but that didn't work, I might have been doing it wrong though. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you just change the class name of the element and have them defined in your css?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: The function is not in a class. I don't know if i'm misunderstanding the question though.

Comment: http://stardomga.me if you click the icons/logos then it changes the div at the top but I'm wanting that color to be a gradient and if i set it to a linear-gradient it doesn't change at all when clicked

Comment: Linear-gradients aren't colors - they are a (kind of) image. You'll need to set a background-image.

Comment: I've had a look at the code in stardomga.me and there are several repeated ids (hover, dscontent, dslogo). This isn't correct HTML. Passing the code through W3C Validator might be useful. (Not related to the actual question I realise!). Where is the eventhandler for changing the color, sorry I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I am Brazilian and therefore I speak Portuguese, but I will use the translator to try to help you.

What you can do is the following:

```
 document.getElementById("your-element-id")
 .style
 .backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(red, yellow)";
```